# Issue transforming popups to popunders

Tags: javascript

so I have a php ad network script, and I wanna convert the popups to popunders and I can't. I've asked chatgpt and none of the answers work, they do trigger a popunder but it says "about:blank" in the url and don't show the url of the pop ads or load anything else than that blank window.

This is what I originally have:

```
if ( !isset($_COOKIE['pop_seen'])){
         header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
     
         echo 'var homepage = document.querySelector("body");

         var popUp = function(e) {
         window.open ("'.$url.'", "Window","status=1,toolbar=1,width='.do_config(75).',height='.do_config(76).',top=300,left=250,resizable=yes");
         homepage.removeEventListener("click", popUp, false);
         }
         homepage.addEventListener("click", popUp, false);';
         exit;
     }
 }
```

Is it enough with changing something there? that's part of the ads model.

I tried the solutions chatgpt gave me and nothing happened, the window shows about:blank

Comment: Since your probably appears to only be client-side, I'm removing the PHP tag in favor just JavaScript.

Comment: Your code snippet is missing the part where `$url` is defined. You should look it up in your script and try to figure out in which case the URL is either set as `about:blank` or not set at all.

Comment: the $url is defined I reckon, cuz if I just use that code, it triggers a popup and gets the pertinent url for it, it's just that when I try to modify them to popunders, it doesn't work. But as it is, it works

Comment: For demo purposes, this is the kind of problem that you can 100% remove all PHP from and try with pure HTML and JS with variables replaced with sample data: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/jOveLgR

Comment: that's really convenient, thanks Chris